# How to Cleanup Django Orphan Foreign Key Values?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery

I'm creating a model that refers to a model within a 3rd party package -- Celery (CrontabSchedule and PeriodicTask).  My model (let's called it ScheduledRun) will contain a foreign key to a PeriodicTask.

I know that a cascade delete will happen if I delete a foreign key *itself*, and that the parents referring to that foreign key will also get deleted.  (Unless overridden by on_delete...)

But due to my situation of pointing ScheduledRun at a FK of a PeriodicTask, PeriodicTask won't be automatically deleted when I delete a ScheduledRun.  (Nor should it as there might be other models pointing to that foreign key!)

So how could I cleanup PeriodicTasks that are orphans -- i.e., when no model instances point to it anymore.

I could add a post_delete signal and check it this way (this example is deleting extraneous CrontabSchedules not associated with a periodic task anymore:

```
# periodictask below is actually a related periodictask_set, 
# but in Django you refer to the empty set as 'periodictask=None'
CrontabSchedule.objects.filter(id=instance.crontab.id,
                               periodictask=None).delete()
```

But I'm not guaranteed there aren't *other* related relations that could cause a cascade drop.

I could subclass the table PeriodicTask as ScheduledRun .... but would rather not integrate that tightly with the 3rd party model.

It's almost as if I want a .delete(do_not_cascade=True) and if it fails due to constraints, just ignore the failure.  If it succeeded, then it was an orphan.  on_delete=DO_NOTHING is similar to this, but I only want it on only *temporarily* for the scope of a single delete, and I don't want to modify the third party package.

Are there other/better ways for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution ... seems like it might be robust enough.  My goal is to only delete the foreign key value if no other model instances still refer to it.

So, what I will try is a delete based on each of the related keys value being None:

```
# This is a class method to my ScheduledRun class that has
# a foreign key to a PeriodicTask.  PeriodicTask has a 
# FK to a CrontabSchedule, which I'd like to "trim"
# if nothing points to that FK anymore.
@classmethod
def _post_delete(cls, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.periodic_task.delete()
    # Delete the crontab if no other tasks point to it.
    # This could cause a cascade if we don't check all related...
    filter = dict(id=instance.crontab.id)
    for related in instance.crontab._meta.get_all_related_objects():
        filter[related.var_name] = None
    assert('id' in filter)
    assert('schedule' in filter)
    assert('periodictask' in filter)
    CrontabSchedule.objects.filter(**filter).delete()
```

It would be easier if I could say:

```
instance.crontab.delete(NO_CASCADE=True)
```